# How to control audio echo and reduce mic gain level using the features of speex codec?

Tags: android, codec, speex

I am testing audio loopback program in android  using speex codec.I am getting severe echo when loudspeaker turned on.speex encode and decode called from separate thread.How to control echo and also reduce the mic gain level.Need simple example or code snippets to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I have a demo app that does exactly that - see that video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1-HwidHMy0

It's a whole project so we can discuss it by email, but for the sake of the answer, you can read my answer to this similar question:

[Android Speex echo cancellation problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080808/android-speex-echo-cancellation-problems)

Comment: Can you share your email?